# Why doesn't Scipy root method converge to the same solution that in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have the following function from which I would like to obtain its solution. I'm trying to use Scipy to get them but I observe that the solution being given by Scipy is quite different from that of Matlab, using same settings.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def WandG(GW,Zin):
    G,W = GW # define real variables to be used for the function

    R = (G**2)*(Zin.real - 0.1164) +(( 70e-12 * ( W/100 ) )**2)*( 2.9036155068866304e+16*(Zin.real - 0.1164) ) - G 

    I = (G**2)*( Zin.imag - 18.743998408378143 * (1-W/200) ) + (((W/100)*70e-12)**2)*( 2.9036155068866304e+16*(Zin.imag - 18.743998408378143 * (1-W/200)) ) + 170399985.53071037*(70e-12*(W/100) )

    return R,I

sol = optimize.root(WandG, [0.136879496, 47.04],(12.652884410928804+14.632724423763523j), jac=False,tol=1e-14, method='lm',options={'maxiter':100*400,'epsfcn':1e-14,'xtol':1e-14})
```

The solution using Scipy would be

```
sol.x[0] = 0.0795283512113496 # G
sol.x[1] = 36.53727146377749  # W
```

Whereas with MATLAB for the same initial conditions, solver and Zin, it returns, which I trust more since it resembles better to the final result of `W` which is `W=50`

```
G = 0.0794
W = 44.5234
```

EDIT : added Matlab code

```
    % configuration of fsolve    
    options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter-detailed','PlotFcn',@optimplotfirstorderopt);
    options.StepTolerance = 1e-14;
    %options.OptimalityTolerance = 1e-14
    options.FunctionTolerance = 1e-14;
    options.MaxIterations = 100000;
    options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 400;
    options.Algorithm = 'levenberg-marquardt';%'trust-region'%
    fun= @WandG;

    x0 = [0.136879496', 47.04'];

    % Solve the function fun
    gw =fsolve(fun,x0,options);

    % Function to be solved by fsolve
    function F = WandG(x)

        F(:,1) = (x(:,1).^2).*(real(Zin) - 0.1164) +(( 70e-12 .* ( x(:,2)./100 ) ).^2).*( w.^2.*(real(Zin) - 0.1164) ) - x(:,1); 

        F(:,2) = (x(:,1).^2).*( img(Zin) - 18.743998408378143 * (1-x(:,2)./200) ) + (((x(:,2)./100).*70e-12).^2).*( 2.9036155068866304e+16*(img(Zin) - 18.743998408378143 .* (1-x(:,2)./200)) ) + 170399985.53071037.*(70e-12.*(x(:,2)./100) );

    end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also provided the MATLAB code...

Comment: I would say it is due to Python Floating Error but W seems to have a large differentation

Comment: @Wolfie I added the matlab code

Comment: You have coefficients of the order `70e-12` and `2.9e+16`, as well as floats given to a lot of decimal places. Without any testing, I'm reading those as red flags for precision errors. Try to output the solution at each iteration in both cases to see when the values diverge.

Comment: Have you tried plugging the computed solution back into `WandG` to check that the solution is a root (to within the specified tolerances)?

Comment: If I plug the scipy solution back into `WandG`, I get `(1.3877787807814457e-17, 2.6020852139652106e-18)`.  If I plug the purported Matlab solution into the Python implementation of `WandG`, I get `(-1.1909217519298632e-05, 0.0056999419140323585)`.  So either the Matlab solution is not very accurate, or the Python implementation of `WandG` does not exactly match the Matlab version.